# About voltage divider resistor network

Tags: voltage-divider

I need a precision decade voltage divider. And there is a [product from Visahy](http://www.vishay.hk/networks-and-arrays/list/product-60044/) just can do what I want. But it's soooooooooo expensive! So

1. Why they are so expensive?
2. I need the ratio tolerance at least ±0.05%. And if it's acceptable the absolute ratios may not be in 'decades' precisely. Can I use several discrete 0.1% metal film resistors in series to achieve this?

Comment: Accuracy is easy. Precision is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things to build your own precision divider, unfortunately you will need to spend *some* money.

a) adjust resistors initially to get the ratio

b) use resistors with good stability, so you keep your ratio

Adjust resistors

It is much easier to match resistors precisely, than to set them. It allows you to use a low-precision DVM to measure the voltage from a Wheatstone bridge to high accuracy.

If you want to make a decade divider and want all the taps, put 10 matched resistors in series. If you need only one tap, put 3 in series, 3 in parallel, and then you have a 9:1 ratio pair of resistors.

Keep their precision

As you spend more money on your resistors, you can get tempcos improved from the standard 200ppm/C to sub 20ppm/C, and the same goes for long-term stability. It can also be worth buying multiple matched resistors in a single package, as often their tracking performance is specified to be better than you could acheive with discrete resistors, because they share temperature, strain, impurities etc

Of course, you could use standard '10 a penny' resistors, and re-check their values before each use.

Comment: Yes, I may spend more money to improve the 'precision'. What about using a MDAC? Not considering the cost now, if it can achieve the goal? I noticed there are products with INL 1lsb, full-scale gain error in several mVs max. And \$TCV_{FS}\$ 1ppm/°C. Such as ADI's AD5543.

Answer (score 1):

*Why they are so expensive?*

Because: *"laser-trimmed to extremely tight tolerances"*

- that takes time and expensive equipment
- The market for such a product is small (mainly measurement equipment).
- It is a product intended for use in professional equipment (i.e. expensive equipment)

Of course you can make such a voltage divider yourself ! If you have a way to measure the division ratio of your divider **accurately** you can tweak the divider to any ratio you want.

It is a similar process to what the Vishay product uses, there the resistors are made too low in value. Then they're laser-trimmed, with this they can only **increase** the resistor's value. So if you stop at the right moment, you can make any value you like.

You can  build a voltage divider and it will not be accurate. Now measure it and keep adding extra series resistors until you achieve your specification.